# Forcing inclussion of a jar using maven assembly plugin with jar-with-dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am trying to package my application in an executable jar. For this I am using the maven-assembly-plugin with the descriptorRef jar-with-dependencies. As my application has some factories that load classes dynamically using reflection, these classes are not included in the final jar. I am wondering if someone knows a way to tell the maven plugin: Hey, add also all the classes in this jar to the resulting jar-with-dependencies.

Comment: That is what the `jar-with-dependencies` already does, what's the issue you have?

Comment: The classes that are loaded using reflection are not included in the final jar as they are not referenced anywhere. I want to know if there's a way to force the inclusion of these classes somehow.

Comment: Why not declare the JAR containing those classes as a dependency?

Comment: The jar containing these classes is declared as dependency already. Even thou I still get a ClassNotFoundException when I execute a Class.forName("com.MyClass") and I suppose this is so because the maven plugin finds no reference to the com.MyClass and thus it doesn't include it in the final jar. I assume this because if I add the class manually to the final jar or I run the application from Eclipse, the class is loaded fine.

Comment: That sounds your dependencies are wrong of your project which creates the assembly..

Comment: The point here is: What do 'with dependencies' mean. Include in the final jar all classes that have a dependency or include all classes in all jars defined in the pom as dependencies?